# How to file a bug on GNOME's bugzilla?

Tags: gnome, bug-reporting

I want to file a bug directly upstream to GNOME.
Can someone give exact procedure for filing bugs on GNOME Bugzilla?

Comment: Are you sure it's a question for Ask Ubuntu? And for filing a bug upstream, there's no general answer, it depends on what bug-tracker the project is using even though you sound sure it's Bugzilla.

Comment: @Oxwivi i just want the procedure for projects using bugzilla .

Comment: [Too many projects](http://www.bugzilla.org/installation-list/) use Bugzilla. Procedures are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before filing a bug report, it is good to search if the bug has already been reported. This saves time and effort.

**Step 1**  Identify which GNOME package you want to file the report on. This might be the most difficult item. Common packages are `gtk+` (for low-level toolkit bugs), `gnome-games` (for any of the games) and so on. You can click on the Help»About menu to find the codename of any application.

**Step 2**  Visit https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi and from the pull-down menu find the product identified in Step 1. Click on `Show product`.

**Step 3** Suppose you want to search for existing bugs in the Text Editor (`gedit`). The URL is [gedit product page on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=gedit). From here you can view a list of all open bugs, perform searches and identify anything related to issues about the application. If do find an existing report for the issue you planned to report, click to *Subscribe* to the bug report, so that you receive updates.

**Step 4** If you did not find a relevant bug report, click on the link *File a bug* in order to write a new bug report (or request for enhancement).

That's it!

**Bonus addition** If you can find a bug report in Launchpad and the corresponding bug report on GNOME's Bugzilla, you can link from Launchpad to GNOME's Bugzilla. And Launchpad will automatically follow the status of the Bugzilla report. This type of connecting reports in Launchpad to Bugzillas is very important for the Ubuntu community and helps put order in the bugs.

Answer (score 2):

For filing a bug in GNOME's bugzilla, look at these instructions from the ubuntu bug team. There are also some tips for how to report bugs on other bugzillas:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Upstream/GNOME
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Upstream

Here are instructions on how to use Bugzilla itself:

- http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.4/en/html/using.html