# Ubuntu Flickering windows

Tags: nautilus, 15.04, flicker

I recently installed nautilus 3.1.12 following this [website](http://sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-nautilus-3-12-2-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/) and it have left me flickering windows. All my browser, ide, options are flickering and it seems like the ui is basic one not gnome. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Checkout other questions regarding this issues on this site (tons popup on the right bar) and share you're research result.

Comment: Likely won't help but I fixed it with: https://askubuntu.com/a/1043655/114641

Answer (score 0):

If you install a package from a staging-repository you have to expect bugs (which programs simply have before they're released as stable versions) and you're encouraged to report this issue at [the GNOME bug tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/). More infos in [How to file a bug on GNOME's bugzilla?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43487/how-to-file-a-bug-on-gnomes-bugzilla). You'll have to wait until it's fixed, a developer suggest a workaround or use a stable version.